# Terminology question; Cross-sectional study and logistic regression - "predictors" or "correlates"?

Tags: regression, logistic, terminology

Is the use of the term "Predictors" with regard to IVs in a logistic regression model appropriate or should an alternative term, such as correlates, be used instead?

Specifically thinking of a cross-sectional design.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what one is doing with it. For example. for [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) one might desire to solve for the [individual probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_log-linear_model), with other possabilities being a set of independent binary regressions, estimating the coefficients, or as a latent-variable model.

One could solve for correlations, but I would take that from the logarithm of a power formula ($Y=X_1^a\;X_2^b\;X_3^c\dots$) to do that (Well, sometimes I would, when it's appropriate).